# django関数ベースでユーザーのログアウト,パスワード変更機能を実装したい

Tags: django

### 1. やりたい・やりたかったこと

django関数ベースでユーザーのログアウト機能，パスワードの再設定を実装したいのですが作り方の書かれているサイトがうまく見つけられないのですが，おすすめのサイトはございますか。

Comment: あわせて読みたい https://teratail.com/questions/353267

Comment: ログアウトは大体ログイン機能のきじに付随しています

Comment: パスワードの再設定は、パスワードリマインダーで検索してみてください

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

次のLoginoutの方法がサイトにてありました。こちらを
参照してください
https://qiita.com/soup01/items/45be5ab213bbff7e5781